# gcc (msys2) not compiling under VSCode

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, gcc

Please see the image below. No errors, just no output either:

[image]

Comment: It will compile from within the MSYS2 terminal - just not inside vscode (v1.73.1)

Answer (score 0):

Update: fixed it.  Apparently needed an update via

```
pacman -Suy
```